# Variable scope within a block in ruby

Tags: ruby, scope, local-variables

I'm struggling with variable scope within a block in ruby. I learnt that **do..end** that follows `while`, `until`, or `for` loops are not blocks because `while`, `until`, or `for` are not method calls. So they don't create their own inner scope. but this example confused me

```
loop do
  b = 2
  p b # => 2
  break
end
p b
```

Here in this example `b` is initialized with the number `2` inside the **do..end**. The puts method is called with the variable `b` passed to it as an argument, and it through an **NameError**. saying that `b` is undefined local variable, but as i said before the
**do..end** that follows `while`, `until`, or `for` loops don't create their own inner scope

Comment: As you mentioned `while`, `until`, and `for` are [keywords](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/doc/keywords_rdoc.html) and do not create a local variable scope. `loop` on the other hand is a method call implemented as [`Kernel#loop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) and it adheres to the same lexical block scoping as other block calls in ruby.

Answer (score 1):

> but as i said before the
> **do..end** that follows `while`, `until`, or `for` loops don't create their own inner scope

Exactly. But there is no `while`, `until`, or `for` loop in your code.